# Is it possible to change the class of a Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, class, object

Is it possible to change the class of a Ruby object once it has been instantiated, something like:

```
class A
end

class B
end

a = A.new
a.class = B
```

or similar.

(the above code does not run as class is a read only variable)

I know this is not advisable, a bit strange, and not something I plan on doing, but is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (Remember the [faq]: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**")

Comment: What would you expect to happen? That a then has all the methods of class B? Because then `a = B.new` would do that.

Comment: It used to be possible: http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/04/ruby_code_that_will_swallow_yo.html

Comment: I wanted to do that.  Mostly for parsing a date.   parse_date!(date), so that date would covert from being a string to a DateTime object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible from within ruby.

It is theoretically possible from within a C extension by changing the `klass` pointer of the given object, but it should be noted that this will be completely implementation-specific, will not work for immediate types (i.e. you definitely can't change the class of e.g. a fixnum), and might blow up in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to convert from the built-in `String` class to a custom class called `MyString`, I did it via the following:

```
class MyString < String
  #Class body here
end

class String
  def to_MyS
    MyString.new self
  end
end

foo = "bar"
puts foo.class #=> String

foo = foo.to_MyS
puts foo.class #=> MyString
```

Comment: This doesn't change the class of `foo`; it creates a brand new instance.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer, no:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `class=' for #<A:0x91a758>
```

however you can delete methods and mix in modules and such so as to leave an object that looks totally different...