# Rails 4 "becomes" issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I have an app that is using the `becomes` method to convert an object into another one. Encoded asset should become `EncodedImage` but it's not saving properly and the `EncodedImage` array remains blank. Although it appears as if it's saving it just doesn't actually store the data in `EncodedImage` object.
 I have the following code:

```
class EncodedAsset < Asset
  serialize :files
  serialize :linked_files
  serialize :linked_files_cache

  belongs_to :video, :foreign_key => :asset_id

  scope :ordered, -> { order("extname ASC, bitrate ASC") }
  scope :mp4s, -> { where(:extname => '.mp4')}
  scope :m3u8s, -> { where(:extname => '.m3u8')}

  validates_presence_of :asset_id

  before_create :set_type

  def get_url(file)
    Saas::Config.primary_s3_bucket_url + file
  end

  protected
    def set_type
      case profile_name
      when 'thumbnail'
        self.becomes(EncodedImage)
      else
        self.becomes(EncodedVideo)
      end
    end

    def is_hls?
      extname.include?('.m3u8')
    end
end
```

The EncodedAsset type remains EncodedAsset when it should become EncodedImage once the thumbnail is uploaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: self.becomes(EncodedImage) should return an instance of an EncodedImage with the current EncodedAsset's attributes... I don't think it will actually turn the current EncodedAsset into an EncodedImage...  I don't really use becomes though, so I'm not that clear on its use

Comment: You cannot mutate the object class in-place as you wish to do. You would only be able to return a different object based on this one.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong method. 
becomes (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) doesn't change the type column in place. You want to use becomes! (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes-21).

Comment: `becomes!` would not solve this problem. The bang, `!` in this case denotes that it also manipulates the `type` attribute, not that it mutates the object.

Comment: Quoting the docs from becomes!:Note: The old instance's sti column value will be changed too, as both objects share the same set of attributes.

Comment: Yes, the type column will be changed, but the actual class of the object will not.

Comment: Look at the source code linked from the documentation you linked to. It creates a new instance with the correct class, and copies the attributes. For the `!` version it mutates the `type` attribute. The original instance is untouched, and will always have it's instantiated type.

The Ruby language does not support this feature. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528552/is-it-possible-to-change-the-class-of-a-ruby-object

Comment: You are correct. But since he said after saving, it implied for me a reload, and then it would have the correct class.

Comment: Question does mention "after saving" anywhere.